# Ansible: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}

Tags: ansible

Can someone help me in understanding and resolving it

```
 - name: Copying file to sever2
    fetch:
      src: /tmp/
      dest: /u0/test/
    when:
      "{{ inventory_hostname == 'testdb' }}"
```

Answer (score 8):

In your case, you should use when condition without Jinja delimiters.

Example:

```yaml
when: inventory_hostname == 'testdb'
```

**Detailed explanation:**

Jinja template delimiters are used when variable interpolation is required in context of text and templates. This tells Ansible to use the value of the variable instead of the variable name.

- *Consider everything as text unless told otherwise (with delimiters)*

Example:

```yaml
  vars:
    fav_tool: Ansible

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "I like fav_tool"
```

This will output:

```
"msg": "I like fav_tool"
```

*This is not what I wanted, I wanted to display "I like Ansible"*. So then I have to "tell" ansible to use the value of `fav_tool`.

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "I like {{ fav_tool }}"
```

Similarly we use Jinja template delimiters in templates. Where we want to separate the variable, and expressions from text.

Example template such as below:

```jinja
if fav_tool == 'Ansible'
I like Ansible
endif
```

... will result in exactly the same text without evaluating:

```
if fav_tool == 'Ansible'
I like Ansible
endif
```

However, when we use Jinja delimiters:

```jinja
{% if fav_tool == 'Ansible' %}
I like Ansible
{% endif %}
```

It will result in:

```
I like Ansible
```

When we use conditions such as `when:`, we don't need delimiters as the conditionals will automatically interpolate the variable to value.

- *Consider everything as variables and expressions unless told otherwise (with `''`)*

Example:

The case is reversed here and whatever is not enclosed in single-quotes is automatically evaluated. Only `'Ansible'` is considered as text here (not evaluated).

```yaml
  vars:
    fav_tool: Ansible

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "Ansible rocks!"
    when: fav_tool == 'Ansible'
```

Comment: a bit frustrating but how do you deal with ":" characters in a string. Jinja2 template delimiters allow a string to have ":" with `{{ ":" }}`

Comment: Not sure of your exact use case, it could justify a new question and other experts may chime in as well.

Comment: Instead of looking at it from a use case perspective, look at it from a language perspective. In a conditional `when:`, you are simply not allowed to have `{{ }}` or `%%` in the statement. This is a problem because `:` is a special character that confuses the parser and cannot be used in a some_statement part in `when: some_statement`. Perhaps it does warrant a question, it seems to be bad language design imo.

Comment: thanks, seshadri_c! Instead of writing "'{{ item.value.group }}' in group_names" in a loop, i could simply write "item.value.group in group_names" in a when condition.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me with

```
    when:
     (inventory_hostname in groups['testdb'])
```

Comment: Thanks! That saved >30 s during gathering facts on node which was down.